# Single node graph not reacting to forceCenter?

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I'm starting a graph project with a single node. When I'm dragging it somewhere, I expect it to smoothly go back to the center of the svg but instead of that, it *glitches* back to the center.

```
var simulation = d3.forceSimulation()
  .force("center", d3.forceCenter(svgWidth/2, svgHeight/2));
```

[Codepen full example](https://codepen.io/mrelemental/pen/QBPQXW)

I think I might not be configuring forceCenter() properly or maybe since there is no other node, there is no other body to interact with so this is how D3 would work.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> ...maybe since there is no other node, there is no other body to interact with so this is how D3 would work.

Yes, your intuition is (partially) correct here, there is nothing wrong with this force simulation. I reckon that the problem here comes from a misunderstanding of the purpose of `forceCenter`: `forceCenter` does not make the node going smoothly to the specified position (more on that below). Actually, if you had another node in that simulation, you'd see that, by dragging one node, the other one would also move, so the center of mass stays at the same place.

That being said, you can see that it works as you expect — that is, the node smoothly going back to the center — if, instead of `forceCenter`, you used `forceX` and `forceY`...

```
var simulation = d3.forceSimulation()
    .force("x", d3.forceX(svgWidth / 2))
    .force("y", d3.forceY(svgHeight / 2));
```

... without changing any `alpha`, `alphaTarget`, `velocityDecay` etc...

Here is the code with that change only:

```js
////////////////////////////////////////////////////
// SVG setup
////////////////////////////////////////////////////
var svgWidth = 400,
    svgHeight = 400;

var svgRef = d3.select("body").append("svg")
  .attr("width",svgWidth)
  .attr("height",svgHeight);

svgRef.append("rect")
  .attr("width", svgWidth)
  .attr("height", svgHeight);

////////////////////////////////////////////////////
// Data
////////////////////////////////////////////////////
var nodes_data = [{id: "0"}];
var links_data = [];

////////////////////////////////////////////////////
// Links and nodes setup
////////////////////////////////////////////////////
var linksRef = svgRef.selectAll(".link")   
.data(links_data).enter()
.append("line")
.attr("class", "link");

var nodesRef = svgRef
.selectAll(".node")
.data(nodes_data).enter()
.append("g").attr("class", "node")
.append("circle")
  .attr("r", 10)
.call(d3.drag()
      .on("start", dragstarted)
      .on("drag", dragged)
      .on("end", dragended));

////////////////////////////////////////////////////
// Simulation setup
////////////////////////////////////////////////////
var simulation = d3.forceSimulation()
  .force("x", d3.forceX(svgWidth / 2))
.force("y", d3.forceY(svgHeight / 2));

simulation.nodes(nodes_data).on("tick", ticked);
simulation.force("link").links(links_data);

function ticked() {
  nodesRef.attr("transform", function (d) {return "translate(" + d.x + "," + d.y + ")";})

  linksRef.attr("x1", function(d) { return d.source.x; })
    .attr("y1", function(d) { return d.source.y; })
    .attr("x2", function(d) { return d.target.x; })
    .attr("y2", function (d) { return d.target.y; });
}

////////////////////////////////////////////////////
// Dragging
////////////////////////////////////////////////////
function dragstarted (d) {
  if (!d3.event.active) simulation.alphaTarget(1).restart();
  d.fx = d.x;
  d.fy = d.y;
}
function dragged (d) {
  d.fx = d3.event.x;
  d.fy = d3.event.y;
}
function dragended (d) {
  if (!d3.event.active) simulation.alphaTarget(0);
  d.fx = null;
  d.fy = null;
}
```

```css
.link {
   stroke: #000;
   stroke-width: 2px;
 }

 .node {
   fill: #CCC;
   stroke: #000;
   stroke-width: 1px;
 }

 rect {
   fill: none;
   stroke: #000;
   stroke-width: 2px;
   pointer-events: all;
 }
```

```html
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v5.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: you said _"center of mass"_ and suddenly everything was clear :) thx